# Trying to compare two strings in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have something like this:

A1: 0069

B1: 030069

In every case, I need to check if A1 is equal to B1 if I were to ignore the 03. I have a lot of cells, and the 03 is just there because its the format of the data. However, A1 can be multiple different lengths, so I can't just use the MID formula and just check B1 after the 03 because I would need to make multiple cases depending on how long A1 is.

Originally, I get the A1 data by using the formula:

D1 =FIND("-",C1), where C1 is A1 in the format: 0069-XXXX-XX.

I then use:

A1 =LEFT(C1,D1-1), which gives me the number 0069 as you see above. This way, I'll always have the correct length when I actually start the real problem.

My question is, can I use some kind of concatenation to just add a 03 to A1 and then see if it is equal to B1. I've tried using & and CONCATENATE, but because they are in general terms, I get the #VALUE error. Maybe I'm just not typing it in correctly, but yea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `&` correctly in A1:

```
="03" & LEFT(C1, D1 - 1)
```

Comment: Yea I had a feeling it was an easy fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To compare these values you could use a formula like below:

```
=IF(A1=RIGHT(B1;4);"true";"false")
```

Actually it is not necessary to use the formula in A1 nor D1, you can use your data from column C straight away:

```
=IF(LEFT(C1;4)=RIGHT(B1;4);"true";"false")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is Column C is nnnn-XXXX-XX then no helper column (Columns A and  D) is necessary:

```
=MID(B1,3,4)=LEFT(C1,4)
```